# how can check user is in stop position or in running position programmatically in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, gps, location, cllocationmanager

I am working in the cllocation manager and get the current location of user but unable to find the user status like user is in running position or stop position . So please help me , How can get its corrent status when user walking programmatically in iphone.

Comment: when 'CLLocationManager' Delegate methods '- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations' will notify you when user's location changes, so when user's location gets changes you can decide he is moving.

Comment: @suraj and when he gets no notification, this does not necessarily  mean that user has stopped. it could be a tunnel, underground, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use the speed attribute of CLLocation, asumimg GPS enabled and set to best accuracy.

```
If (loc.speed > 7/3.6) then running
```

walking: < 6 km/h

stopped is more difficult: no location update (measured with a timer)
But you cannot distinguish between "stopped" and "no GPS available" (e.g in underground, or indoors). That would need the acceleration sensor, if the state needs to be in real time.